# How do I change color of a text after clicking on it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying  hard to change the text color after clicking on it but not getting success.
There are seven labels :- one for question, four for answer options, one for correct answer and last one for explanation.

When click on any one option then it should match with the correct answer and change the color of the text i.e. if the answer is wrong then color of the text should turn to red and if the answer is right then turn green.

But when I click on any option then it is changing to red color only and When I click on the option which is correct according to the correct answer then also it turn to red instead of green. I can't figure out why ?
Have a look at my code. Show me where I am making mistake and what is the solution.

The jquery for changing color is between line number 48 and 82

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
    //$("#Panel2").hide();
    document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function () {
        return false;
    }//Avoid Reloading
    $(".panelButton").click(function () {
        var $thisButton = $(this); //save button into a variable
        var $ansPanel = $(this).parent().find('.AnswerPanel'); //save ans panel into a variable

        if ($ansPanel.is(":hidden")) {
            $ansPanel.show();
        }
        else {
            $ansPanel.hide();
        }

        if ($thisButton.val() == "Show Answer") {
            $thisButton.val("Hide Answer");
        } else {
            $thisButton.val("Show Answer");
        }
    });

    $(".optionclass").click(function () {
        var $thisoption = $(this);
        var $corrans = $(".correctans");

        if ($thisoption.text() == $corrans.text()) {
            $thisoption.css("color", "green");
        }
        else {
            $thisoption.css("color", "red");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <span>A-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>B-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>C-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>D-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4")%>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button class="panelButton" runat="server" Text="Show Answer" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />

            <asp:Panel ID="anspanel" class="AnswerPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

                <span>Correct Answer is :-</span><asp:Label class="correctans" ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAns")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Explanation")%>'></asp:Label>


            </asp:Panel>


        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

       
    </div>
          <div id="tabs-2">
            </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Tab 3 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">
        Tab 4 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">
        Tab 5 Content
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnPrevious" value="Previous" style = "display:none"/>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" />

    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML rather than the server-side code? We can't know how it looks like just from this.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated use `.on()` instead for this.

Comment: Why do you have multiple document ready event handlers? ` $(function () {` You should only have one if at all possible

Comment: THIS: `if ($ansPanel.is(":hidden")) {
                $ansPanel.show();
            }
            else {
                $ansPanel.hide();
            }` can simply be THIS: `$ansPanel.toggle();`

Comment: What does this result in: `console.log($thisoption.text() +":"+ $corrans.text())` if put right there in that function?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't want to print any messages, I just want to change the color of the text. Look at my edited question, I removed all unrelated stuff.

Comment: But what does that show?  Are they actually equal?  THAT is the point of that.  Remove it once you see the values...Either that or  use the debugger in Visual Studio for this.

Comment: For server side tags, you should use `CssClass="optionclass"`, I think ASP.NET would strip unknown attributes, so you don't have any class in the generated HTML

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I used your technique and found that `$corrans` contain only one value(i.e. 1/8) and compare with different values of `$thisoption` but when text matched it dosen't turn to green. Every time when I click on the option it turn to red color only.

Comment: I mocked up your page here so you can test: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/q9xa4qt0/  Seems to work given my mocked up values.  You might post the actual RENDERED page html that might reveal some differences.

Comment: I am doing same to same as you did but when I click on any option it turn to red only. Another thing I noticed is :- when I replace `$thisoption.textl() == $corrans.text()` with`$thisoption.val() == $corrans.val()` then every option is turning to green when I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is fine, you just don't have any data in your Label tags. Just add some text in your label tags.**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var currentTab = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (e, i) {
                currentTab = i.index;
            }
        });
    });
    $("#btnNext").live("click", function () {
        var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var c = $('#tabs').tabs("length");
        currentTab = currentTab == (c - 1) ? currentTab : (currentTab + 1);
        tabs.tabs('select', currentTab);
        $("#btnPrevious").show();
        if (currentTab == (c - 1)) {
            $("#btnNext").hide();
        } else {
            $("#btnNext").show();
        }
    });
    $("#btnPrevious").live("click", function () {
        var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var c = $('#tabs').tabs("length");
        currentTab = currentTab == 0 ? currentTab : (currentTab - 1);
        tabs.tabs('select', currentTab);
        if (currentTab == 0) {
            $("#btnNext").show();
            $("#btnPrevious").hide();
        }
        if (currentTab < (c - 1)) {
            $("#btnNext").show();
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        //$("#Panel2").hide();
        document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function () {
            return false;
        }//Avoid Reloading
        $(".panelButton").click(function () {
            var $thisButton = $(this); //save button into a variable
            var $ansPanel = $(this).parent().find('.AnswerPanel'); //save ans panel into a variable

            if ($ansPanel.is(":hidden")) {
                $ansPanel.show();
            }
            else {
                $ansPanel.hide();
            }

            if ($thisButton.val() == "Show Answer") {
                $thisButton.val("Hide Answer");
            } else {
                $thisButton.val("Show Answer");
            }
        });

        $(".optionclass").click(function () {
            var $thisoption = $(this);
            var $corrans = $(".correctans");

            if ($thisoption.text() == $corrans.text()) {
                $thisoption.css("color", "green");
            }
            else {
                $thisoption.css("color", "red");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <span>A-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1")%>'> CLICK</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>B-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2")%>'>CLICK</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>C-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3")%>'>CLICK</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>D-</span> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4")%>'>CLICK</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button class="panelButton" runat="server" Text="Show Answer" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />

            <asp:Panel ID="anspanel" class="AnswerPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

                <span>Correct Answer is :-</span><asp:Label class="correctans" ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAns")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Explanation")%>'></asp:Label>


            </asp:Panel>


        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

       
    </div>
          <div id="tabs-2">
            </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Tab 3 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">
        Tab 4 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">
        Tab 5 Content
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnPrevious" value="Previous" style = "display:none"/>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" />

    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All these labels are under  gridview so it will fetch data from database and display on the labels.